# Why doesn't Python have a "__req__" (reflected equality) method?

Tags: python, numpy, python-internals, python-datamodel

I have a little helper class:

```
class AnyOf(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.elements = args
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other in self.elements
```

This lets me do sweet magic like:

```
>>> arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> arr == AnyOf(2,3)
np.array([False, True, True, False, False])
```

without having to use a list comprehension (as in `np.array(x in (2,3) for x in arr`).

(I maintain a UI that lets (trusted) users type in arbitrary code, and `a == AnyOf(1,2,3)` is a lot more palatable than a list comprehension to the non-technically savvy user.)

However!

This only works one way! For example, if I were to do `AnyOf(2,3) == arr` then my `AnyOf` class's `__eq__` method never gets called: instead, the NumPy array's `__eq__` method gets called, which internally (I would presume) calls the `__eq__` method of all its elements.

This lead me to wonder: why does Python not allow a right-sided equivalent to `__eq__`? (Roughly equivalent to methods like `__radd__`, `__rmul__`, et cetera.)

Comment: "Why does Python not have X?" isn't likely to be a very productive question. If you want Python to have X, the productive way to make that happen is to follow [the process in PEP-1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0001/#start-with-an-idea-for-python) to actually propose the idea and get feedback from the people who have a say on what gets added to the language. Otherwise, "Is there a way to get the useful effect of X in Python?" is much more likely to actually have an immediately useful result (wrt. generating light rather than heat).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588776/how-is-eq-handled-in-python-and-in-what-order

Comment: Actually I can't recognize an urgent need for a class in the example above. Why not use a simple function, which returns a list?

Comment: Note that if you have somewhat large arrays this "magic" is going to be much slower than something like `np.in1d`.

Comment: Normally, `__eq__` should return `NotImplemented` rather than `False`, unless it is absolutely certain that values are different.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246983/compare-assert-equality-of-two-complex-data-structures-containing-numpy-arrays

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An `__req__` may have been considered more confusing than *useful* in the language. Consider if class `Left` defines `__eq__` and class `Right` defines `__req__`, then Python is obliged to make a *consistent* decision about who gets called first in `Left() == Right()` (and we would presumably like the result to be equivalent, either way). They can't both win.

However, the Python datamodel does allow a way to do what you want here.  The comparison can be controlled from either side of the operation, but you'll need to define `AnyOf` in a particular way.  **To control the **eq** from the right hand side of a comparison when the left side is an `np.ndarray` instance, `AnyOf` should be a subclass of `np.ndarray`.**

> if I were to do `AnyOf(2,3) == arr` then my `AnyOf` class's `__eq__` method never gets called

Actually, no, there's a fundamental misunderstanding evident here. The left side *always* gets first try at handling the equality comparison, unless the right side type is a subclass of the left side type.

```
arr == AnyOf(2,3)
```

In the comparison shown above, your custom `__eq__` *is* being called, because the numpy array calls it!  So `np.ndarray` wins, and it decides to check once per element.  It literally could do anything else, including not calling your `AnyOf.__eq__` at all.

```
AnyOf(2,3) == arr
```

In the comparison shown above, your class does get the first try at the comparison, and it fails because of the way `in` was used - `return other in self.elements`  is checking if an array is in a tuple.

Comment: Regarding "An `__req__` is not a good idea in the language" and the argument that follows, I don't think that holds, as from the same argument, methods like `__radd__` would also not be a good idea. However, I do see now that, due to how which model is selected (`Left.__eq__` or `Right.__req__`) it would actually make it so that `__req__` would fulfill the exact same function as `__eq__`, making the right-hand method superfluous!

Answer (score 5):

This is the documentation on the [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__):

> There are no swapped-argument versions of these methods (to be used when the left argument does not support the operation but the
>   right argument does); rather, `__lt__()` and `__gt__()` are each other’s
>   reflection, `__le__()` and `__ge__()` are each other’s reflection, and
>   **`__eq__()`** and `__ne__()` are their own reflection. If the operands are of different types, and right operand’s type is a direct or indirect
>   subclass of the left operand’s type, the reflected method of the right
>   operand has priority, otherwise the left operand’s method has
>   priority. Virtual subclassing is not considered.

As stated in the comments above, what you want works, and `__eq__` is essentially the sames as a potential `__req__`: it is called on the right hand side of `==` if the object on the left hand side returns `NotImplemented`:

```
In [1]: class A:
   ...:     def __eq__(self, other):
   ...:         return NotImplemented
   ...:     

In [2]: class B:
   ...:     def __eq__(self, other): 
   ...:         print("B comparing")
   ...:         return True
   ...:     

In [3]: B() == A()
B comparing
Out[3]: True

In [4]: A() == B()
B comparing
Out[4]: True

In [5]: A() == A()
Out[5]: False
```

As it comes, it even work with other, ordinary, objects:

```
In [10]: 5 == B()
B comparing
Out[10]: True
```

However, some objects may yield a TypeError on `__eq__` instead of returning `NotImplemented` or `False`, and that makes this not reliable for all kinds of objects.

What happens in your case, is an incorrect use of the operator `in`  with arrays and tuples inside your own `__eq__` method. (Thanks @wim to have spotted this in another answer here).

Comment: +1  that's a big "if" though - some standard types will just raise exception instead of returning `NotImplemented`, so you can't rely on this.

Comment: I'm just not sure it works with `np.array` that way. But if it doesn't it's a bug in `np.array`, not something missing from the language.

Comment: I did not say one can rely on it.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) about the `__rxx__` methods like `__radd__` states:

> These functions are only called if the left operand does not support the
> corresponding operation and the operands are of different types.

While classes don't have `__add__` or `__sub__` methods per default, they **do** have `__eq__`:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     pass
>>> '__eq__' in dir(A)
True
```

This means `__req__` would never be called unless you explicitly remove `__eq__` from the other class or make `__eq__` return `NotImplemented`.

You can solve your specific problem with `np.in1d`:

```
>>> np.in1d(arr, [2, 3])
array([False,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: *This means `__req__` would never be called unless you explicitly remove `__eq__` from the other class* <-- that is not correct, it only needs to opt-out by returning `NotImplemented`, and indeed that's actually the default behavior which is inherited from `object.__eq__` - it implements equality by identity ("is"), and returns `NotImplemented` in the case of a non-identical comparison.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  Corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to know exactly what the CPython interpreter does when it encounters `a == b`.

```py
import dis

def eq(a, b):
    return a == b

print(dis.dis(eq))
```

This gives you:

```
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              4 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

So, it uses the `COMPARE_OP` op. [Here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2897142d2ec0930a8991af964c798b68fb6dcadd/Python/bytecodes.c#L2113C19-L2113C39) is the code which handles this.
(Btw, when looking at earlier versions of CPython, the eval frame code was much simpler and much easier to follow. Now it is heavily optimized now for speed. I'm looking at the current master here.)

You see that this uses the `PyObject_RichCompare` function. We find that [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2897142d2ec0930a8991af964c798b68fb6dcadd/Objects/object.c#L822).

The relevant logic is this:

```c
/* For Python 3.0.1 and later, the old three-way comparison has been
   completely removed in favour of rich comparisons.  PyObject_Compare() and
   PyObject_Cmp() are gone, and the builtin cmp function no longer exists.
   The old tp_compare slot has been renamed to tp_as_async, and should no
   longer be used.  Use tp_richcompare instead.

   See (*) below for practical amendments.

   tp_richcompare gets called with a first argument of the appropriate type
   and a second object of an arbitrary type.  We never do any kind of
   coercion.

   The tp_richcompare slot should return an object, as follows:

    NULL if an exception occurred
    NotImplemented if the requested comparison is not implemented
    any other false value if the requested comparison is false
    any other true value if the requested comparison is true

  The PyObject_RichCompare[Bool]() wrappers raise TypeError when they get
  NotImplemented.

  (*) Practical amendments:

  - If rich comparison returns NotImplemented, == and != are decided by
    comparing the object pointer (i.e. falling back to the base object
    implementation).

*/

/* Map rich comparison operators to their swapped version, e.g. LT <--> GT */
int _Py_SwappedOp[] = {Py_GT, Py_GE, Py_EQ, Py_NE, Py_LT, Py_LE};

static const char * const opstrings[] = {"<", "<=", "==", "!=", ">", ">="};

/* Perform a rich comparison, raising TypeError when the requested comparison
   operator is not supported. */
static PyObject *
do_richcompare(PyThreadState *tstate, PyObject *v, PyObject *w, int op)
{
    richcmpfunc f;
    PyObject *res;
    int checked_reverse_op = 0;

    if (!Py_IS_TYPE(v, Py_TYPE(w)) &&
        PyType_IsSubtype(Py_TYPE(w), Py_TYPE(v)) &&
        (f = Py_TYPE(w)->tp_richcompare) != NULL) {
        checked_reverse_op = 1;
        res = (*f)(w, v, _Py_SwappedOp[op]);
        if (res != Py_NotImplemented)
            return res;
        Py_DECREF(res);
    }
    if ((f = Py_TYPE(v)->tp_richcompare) != NULL) {
        res = (*f)(v, w, op);
        if (res != Py_NotImplemented)
            return res;
        Py_DECREF(res);
    }
    if (!checked_reverse_op && (f = Py_TYPE(w)->tp_richcompare) != NULL) {
        res = (*f)(w, v, _Py_SwappedOp[op]);
        if (res != Py_NotImplemented)
            return res;
        Py_DECREF(res);
    }
    /* If neither object implements it, provide a sensible default
       for == and !=, but raise an exception for ordering. */
    switch (op) {
    case Py_EQ:
        res = (v == w) ? Py_True : Py_False;
        break;
    case Py_NE:
        res = (v != w) ? Py_True : Py_False;
        break;
    default:
        _PyErr_Format(tstate, PyExc_TypeError,
                      "'%s' not supported between instances of '%.100s' and '%.100s'",
                      opstrings[op],
                      Py_TYPE(v)->tp_name,
                      Py_TYPE(w)->tp_name);
        return NULL;
    }
    return Py_NewRef(res);
}
```

That shows that you can indeed return `NotImplemented` in your `__eq__` and how it is handled.

`tp_richcompare` could be overwritten by a custom type. But in the default case, it should be [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2897142d2ec0930a8991af964c798b68fb6dcadd/Objects/typeobject.c#L8946). So as expected, usually this should call `__eq__` etc.