# Can I force python to use the comparison operator implementation of the right hand operand?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, operator-overloading

I am writing a test utility to make assertions with pandas Series easier. For example I would like to be able to write `assert my_series == Constant(3)` to check that all the elements of the Series are equal to 3. To do so I have created a class `Constant` redefining the comparison operators :

```py
import pandas as pd

class Constant:
    
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value
    
    def __eq__(self, other: pd.Series):
        return (other == self._value).all()
```

But depending on the operand order, my comparison implementation is not always used by Python :

```py
s = pd.Series([3]*10)

print("Constant(3) == s :")
print(Constant(3) == s)   # GOOD : Constant.__eq__ is called

print("s == Constant(3)")
print(s == Constant(3))   # BAD : Series.__eq__ is called
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47578057/13299849) I could solve this by defining `Constant` as a subclass of `Series`. But if I want `Constant` to work with several array-like types I have to make it inheriting from `Series`, `DataFrame`, `ndarray` etc... It would make a very strange object with a lot of useless attributes and methods.

What is the best solution ? For example, is there a way to add several array-like types as base classes of `Constant` and then remove all the inherited elements ?

Comment: Technical solutions aside, I think any equality test should always be commutative. If this can't hold true, it may be a good idea to just create a separate function `compare_constants(a, b)` and do custom comparison in it.

Comment: @ernest_k I believe Python designers believe that too, hence why we don't have `__req__`

Comment: Of course, a function would definitely do the job. But for readability reasons I would use this solution as a last resort.

Comment: @nocibor I doubt that it's a good idea. Semantically, `Constant(3)` is not equivalent to `s`.

Comment: @DeepSpace I would use `pandas.testing` internaly. My purpose is to ensure the best readability for non-technical users.

Comment: @Expurple To be more precise, all my `Series` represent signal evolutions over time. In that case `s == Constant(3)` make sense to my mind.

Comment: `numpy` has an `__array_priority__` that allows `ndarray` subclasses to control the operation.